# fftw3 delegate for ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, fftw

I installed fftw3 package for Ubuntu 11.10, then installed ImageMagick. While performing fft of images, i get following error

```
convert: delegate library support not built-in `framed_clown.jpg' (FFTW) @ warning/fourier.c/ForwardFourierTransformImage/611.
```

there was no fftw delegate listed on

```
convert -list configure
```

how can i resolve this ??

Answer (score 2):

I believe that uninstalling imagemagick, installing fftw and reinstalling IM afterwards should solve the problem.

For Windows users there are these precompiled binaries - http://blog.astrophotographytargets.com/2012/03/imagemagick-with-fftw-delegate-library-on-windows/